# Customise to moment.js fromNow above a specified period

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to display the relative time:

```
<time datetime="2014-01-29 17:06:07">29 January 2014 15:06pm</time>

$('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));
    $(e).find('span').html(time.fromNow());
});
```

How can I customise it to display the full date and time if the time lapsed is past a specified period such as 1 month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));

    var s = time.isBefore(moment().subtract(1,'months'))
              ? moment.format() // optionally pass a format specifier if you like
              : time.fromNow();

    $(e).find('span').html(s);
});
```